# How to index numerical data to azure search using analyzeForm power skill?

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-search, azure-form-recognizer

I am using Form recognizer and power skill code AnalyzeFormV2 provided by microsoft in the documentation to create a custom skill to index pdf contents. I used the labelling tool to train the data using custom labels. Some of the data in the pdf are numerical for which I am selecting the type as 'number' in the labelling tool.
After training the form recognizer returns the numerical fields as :

```
        "TotalCredit": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "text": "350.00",
                        "page": 1,
                        "boundingBox": [
                            7.365,
                            5.755,
                            7.705,
                            5.755,
                            7.705,
                            5.855,
                            7.365,
                            5.855
                        ],
                        "confidence": 0.799
                    }
```

The AnalyzeForm API using the azure power skill returns the field like this :

```
"TotalCredit": null
```

It returns all other fields which are string correctly.

Is it a bug of the power skill code? The code uses `recognized[v] =  field.value` to assign the values to the mapped labels. This field.value comes from some 'form_recognizer_client' library. So I dont know how to transform the value to the needed format.
Any thoughts/help on this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, the line should be updated to

```
recognized[v] =  field.value or field.value_data.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the form recognizer is not able to recognize numeric text. That's why it shows the value as `null`. I added `field.value_data.text` and changed it to `float` in the power skills code. This worked for me.

```
if field.value_type == 'string':
   val = field.value 
elif field.value_type == 'float':
   text = field.value_data.text
   val = text.replace(',','')
   val = float(val)
```